# Residual diagnostics in Dynamic Factor Models (DFM)

Tags: time-series, econometrics, diagnostic

I am quite new to Dynamic Factor Models. My main task is to estimate the model on my training data and test the model on my test data set.

My question is, should we perform **residual diagnostics** to an estimated dynamic factor model to check the model adequacy?

Your thoughts on the above  question is greatly appreciated. Any prevailing literature on these areas would also be really helpful.

Comment: There are several different models called Dynamic Factor Model. Could you specify the details? Regarding residual diagnostics, it is always good to do that, as that tells you to which extent the model misrepresents the patterns in the data (hopefully to a small extent) and to which extent you can trust the implications of the model.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you for your response. I was working with DynamicFactorMQ [link](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.dynamic_factor_mq.DynamicFactorMQ.html) and DynamicFactor [link](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.dynamic_factor.DynamicFactor.html) in python. DynamicFactorMQ does not allow exogenous variables while DynamicFactor does. The error distribution is specified in 2 different ways.  A detailed explanation is provided briefly in the links I mentioned.

Comment: @RichardHardy In Dynamic factor models, the idiosyncratic component is assumed to be normally distributed and cross-sectionally uncorrelated. However the dynamics of  idiosyncratic component can be either serially uncorrelated or follow an AR(1) process. I used the latter case.  Hence,is it meaningful to test for autocorrelation since it is allowed in the model? Or am I understanding the concept in a wrong manner? My residual diagnostic plots show serial autocorrelation.

Comment: You could test whether the idiosyncratic component indeed follows an AR(1) process. If the residuals of an AR(1) model of the idiosyncratic component are autocorrelated, then this would not be the case.

Comment: @RichardHardy Sorry, I couldn't understand the point you made. Is it that I should not test for serial autocorrelation if I allow the idiosyncratic component to follow an AR(1) process?

Comment: The point is to test whether your model's assumptions are satisfied, or rather, whether they are violated. If your model assumes AR(1) errors, you can assess that. There is no need to assess whether they are not autocorrelated, because you are not assuming that in the first place.

Comment: Essentially, you have two rather different questions in your post, so it could be considered too broad. I have answered one of them. Consider splitting off the other question into a new thread. This way we can keep track of what has been answered and what it still missing.

Comment: @RichardHardy I edited the Q accordingly. Will ask the other question in a new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding residual diagnostics, it is always good to do that, as that tells you to which extent the model misrepresents the patterns in the data (hopefully to a small extent) and to which extent you can trust the implications of the model.

> the dynamics of idiosyncratic component can be either serially uncorrelated or follow an AR(1) process. I used the latter case. Hence, is it meaningful to test for autocorrelation since it is allowed in the model?

You could test whether the idiosyncratic component indeed follows an AR(1) process. If the residuals of an AR(1) model of the idiosyncratic component are autocorrelated, then this would not be the case. (The point is to test whether your model's assumptions are satisfied, or rather, whether they are violated. If your model assumes AR(1) errors, you can assess that. There is no need to assess whether they are not autocorrelated, because you are not assuming that in the first place.)

Comment: really appreciate the clear explanation! Thank you!